# Вопрос по АД авторизации (LDAP) PHP, как получить данные с корп компьютера?

Tags: php, active-directory

Получается при включении компьютера ты вводишь логин и пароль АД учетки включаешь его, как после получить эти данные или токен о том что ты уже АД авторизовался что бы сайт на php получил автоматом при входе ( что он должен получить?) и сразу авторизовал тебя без ввода логина пароля на сайт?
Можете пожалуйста рассказать мне как все это будет происходить логику АД авторизации на php

Comment: Например, [Apache + kerberos + AD](https://www.google.com/search?ei=bvc3XYe9K4mdsAe4xbqYBQ&q=apache+kerberos+active+directory&oq=apache+kerberos+ac&gs_l=psy-ab.3.0.0i203j0i22i30l9.2753.3222..4720...0.0..0.94.262.3......0....1..gws-wiz.Mt0ezBzq9zg)

Comment: это называется "проброс авторизации", протокол бывает NTLM и kerberos. Не все браузеры пробрасывают авторизацию. Хром по-умолчанию пробрасывает (по F12 сеть, можно даже увидеть заголовки авторизации), фоксу нужно разрешить в настройках. И ещё, сервер php должен быть в домене, и в домене должны быть сгенерированы ключи для проброса.